Запуск одного файла exe с нескольких пк
Написал бота на python и сконвертировал его в exe файл. Чтобы бот работал, надо этот ехе запустить. Могу ли я запустить одновременно с нескольких пк этот ехе-шник, чтобы в случае выключения одного из компьютеров второй был на подстраховке, и бот не упал? Может, надо что то добавить в код исполняемого файла? В интернете не нашел такую информацию.

Можно что-то вроде пинга придумать‍♀️

Может вам Docker и kubernetes нужен?

Зависит от того, чем бот занимается, какие данные использует, изменяет и т.п.

Можно запускать на всех компьютерах Вселенной, если боты не будут мешать друг другу, искажая зависимые данные.

Ну и про балансировщик на nginx можно почитать.
